# Count Boolean Operators

Tags: excel, count, boolean, userform, vba

I've created a userform where some fields are required.  Their name ends with an "R" for easy identification.  However, I can't figure out how to count the number of blank fields flagged by the boolean fields.  If the number of "True" flags is greater than 0, I want to display an error message.

```
For Each ctl In NewAsset.Controls
If Right(ctl.Name, 1) = "R" Then
    If ctl.Value = "" Then
        flag = True
    End If

    If ctl.Value <> "" Then
        flag = False
    End If
End If
Next
```

Comment: You don't need to count the number of trues. if any ctl.Value = "" then throw up a message box and exit the sub.  Once one is blank you can be done checking.

Comment: @sous2817 - That is poor UX - it's much easier from a user standpoint to know *all* of the validation errors at the same time.

Comment: @Comintern Sure, but wouldn't it be better still to not let the user submit the form until the required fields are complete?  Many ways to skin this cat, I gave but one option.

Comment: @sous2817 Fair enough - mainly depends on what the form looks like (number of fields, how many required, etc.).

Comment: The form has 12 inputs, 8 of which are required.  I would like to only have response window.  After the user presses "process," it will either display an error if not all required fields are filled, or confirm inputs if all required fields are filled.  Previous attempts ended with a line by line check and I ended up with 12 separate response text box by text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim n As Long
For Each ctl In NewAsset.Controls
    If Right(ctl.Name, 1) = "R" And ctl.Value = "" Then
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next
If n > 0 Then MsgBox n & " required fields are not filled!"
```

Comment: I used another If Then instead of the and statement and then it worked perfectly!! Thank you!